# org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: invalid code lengths set dlib

Tags: android

`"Cause: invalid code lengths set"` error. The run tasks ended at App:packageDebug. From the long list of things, three under compiler are more informative I guess:

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: invalid code lengths set

java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Still waiting to inspect output APK's res/raw/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
```

On the right side there was: `org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.`
I searched all over the places and tried everything I could find, but it did not work. Also, I cleaned the cache and restarted, I tried different emulator and devices. I also tried different project settings and structure settings. I also noticed that a very similar post was not answered: build failed because of `"org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: invalid code lengths set"`

Comment: Am struggling with this issue since last 2 days, any quick help should be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post your module level gradle file?

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.androidSupportSdkVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support. Deaign:28.0.0" 
    implementation 'com.github.dexafree:materiallist:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    implementation project(':dlib')
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${rootProject.ext.androidSupportSdkVersion}"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
}

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow,please format your question properly see how to ask a good question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask